# Difficult integral $\int_0^{\infty} \frac{x^{n-1}e^{-x}}{(n-1)!}e^{-x/n}dx$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration

I am having issues computing the following integral, $$\int_0^{\infty} \frac{x^{n-1}e^{-x}}{(n-1)!}e^{-x/n}dx.$$

The problem I have is that I cannot figure out a way to get "the $x$" to disappear. So I have tried the following:

$$I\cdot(n-1)! = \int_0^{\infty} x^{n-1}e^{-x(1+\frac{1}{n})}dx = \left[ \frac{x^{n-1}e^{-x(1+\frac{1}{n})}}{\frac{1}{n}+1} \right]_0^{\infty} + \frac{n-1}{1+\frac{1}{n}} \int_0^{\infty} x^{n-2}e^{-x(1+\frac{1}{n})} dx,$$

etc. This is the only way I can think of, but clearly it is not working since it just keeps going. I had some idea that perhaps at some point we would have $x^{n-n}$ in the expression, but I don't know how to make that happen or if that is a good idea.

The answer is supposed to be (I hope) $\left(\frac{n}{n+1}\right)^n$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\frac{1}{(n-1)!}\int_{[0, \infty)}x^{n-1}e^{-x(1+1/n)}dx$$
Let $n\xi=x(n+1)$, then the integral becomes
$$\frac{1}{(n-1)!}\frac{n}{n+1}(\frac{n}{n+1})^{n-1}\int_{[0, \infty)}\xi^{n-1}e^{-\xi}d\xi$$
The integral
$$\int_{[0, \infty)}\xi^{n-1}e^{-\xi}d\xi=(n-1)!=\Gamma(n)$$
is the gamma function.
So,
$$\frac{1}{(n-1)!}\int_{[0, \infty)}x^{n-1}e^{-x(1+1/n)}dx=\Big(\frac{n}{n+1}\Big)^{n}$$

Comment: That was amazing. Although I would have never come up with the idea of putting $n\xi = x(n+1)$ myself. It is not quite clear to me why the integral in the third row equals $\Gamma(n)$, but I guess that is because I don't know enough about the gamma function.

Comment: This integral is one of the definitions of the Gamma function, it extends its definition to all $n\in\mathbb{C}^{2}\smallsetminus\{-1, -2, -3, ...\}$